# How to count the rows that are above average in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query, however I can not succeed on showing the number of `pages` that their `percent_diff` is above the column's average.

What am I missing here?

```
SELECT count(page) from
(
select * FROM pages_diff where company_id = 3 
group by page
having percent_diff > avg(percent_diff)
) nested
```

Comment: Is it returning 0?

Comment: @jagad89 yes it returns 0

Comment: Is it like that, each page having only one record?

Comment: @jagad89 yes exactly

Comment: I think @poofeg is right, but for your scenario you don't need inner condition. `SELECT count(page) FROM pages_diff
WHERE company_id = 3 AND percent_diff > (
  SELECT avg(percent_diff) FROM pages_diff
  )`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be the solution:

```
SELECT count(page) FROM pages_diff
WHERE company_id = 3 AND percent_diff > (
  SELECT avg(percent_diff) FROM pages_diff
  WHERE company_id = 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. With your base query the fastest (to write) would be something like this:

```
SELECT above_avg,below_avg from
(
select count(page) as above_avg FROM pages_diff where company_id = 3 
group by page
having percent_diff > avg(percent_diff)
) nested_above
,
(
select count(page) as below_avg FROM pages_diff where company_id = 3 
group by page
having percent_diff < avg(percent_diff)
) nested_below
```

Alternative you could just get avg and then use if statement. You would still go through the table twice (once to get avg, once to do count on two columns at once)

Comment: thank you, but I am getting a "uknown column percent_diff in having clause"

Comment: percent_diff was not your column?